# Why doesn't SMO scripter generate foreign key headers?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, smo

I'm creating a program to generate my database schema using the SMO libraries distributed with SQL Server 2008.

I've gotten the scripter outputting code which is virtually the same as SQL Server Management Studio outputs when it's configured to output everything, but with one curious exception: it doesn't output comment headers for the foreign key constraints it generates at the bottom, whereas SSMS does.  Can anyone figure out why this is?  Here's my code:

```
private void btnExportScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs ea) {
    Server srv = setupConnection();

    // Reference the database
    if (!srv.Databases.Contains(cbChooseDb.SelectedItem.ToString())) {
        _utils.ShowError("Couldn't find DB '" + cbChooseDb.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'.");
        return;
    }
    Database db = srv.Databases[cbChooseDb.SelectedItem.ToString()];

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Scripter scrp = new Scripter(srv);
        scrp.Options.AppendToFile = false;
        scrp.Options.ToFileOnly = false;
        scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = false;             // Don't script DROPs
        scrp.Options.Indexes = true;                  // Include indexes
        scrp.Options.DriAllConstraints = true;        // Include referential constraints in the script
        scrp.Options.Triggers = true;                 // Include triggers
        scrp.Options.FullTextIndexes = true;          // Include full text indexes
        scrp.Options.NonClusteredIndexes = true;      // Include non-clustered indexes
        scrp.Options.NoCollation = false;             // Include collation
        scrp.Options.Bindings = true;                 // Include bindings
        scrp.Options.SchemaQualify = true;            // Include schema qualification, eg. [dbo]
        scrp.Options.IncludeDatabaseContext = false;
        scrp.Options.AnsiPadding = true;
        scrp.Options.FullTextStopLists = true;
        scrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = false;
        scrp.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;
        scrp.Options.ExtendedProperties = true;
        scrp.Options.ClusteredIndexes = true;
        scrp.Options.FullTextCatalogs = true;
        scrp.Options.SchemaQualifyForeignKeysReferences = true;
        scrp.Options.XmlIndexes = true;
        scrp.Options.IncludeHeaders = true;

        // Prefectching may speed things up
        scrp.PrefetchObjects = true;

        var urns = new List<Urn>();

        // Iterate through the tables in database and script each one.
        foreach (Table tb in db.Tables) {
            if (tb.IsSystemObject == false) {
                // Table is not a system object, so add it.
                urns.Add(tb.Urn);
            }
        }

        // Iterate through the views in database and script each one.  Display the script.
        foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.View view in db.Views) {
            if (view.IsSystemObject == false) {
                // View is not a system object, so add it.
                urns.Add(view.Urn);
            }
        }

        // Iterate through the stored procedures in database and script each one.  Display the script.
        foreach (StoredProcedure sp in db.StoredProcedures) {
            if (sp.IsSystemObject == false) {
                // Procedure is not a system object, so add it.
                urns.Add(sp.Urn);
            }
        }

        // Start by manually adding DB context
        builder.AppendLine("USE [" + db.Name + "]");
        builder.AppendLine("GO");

        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = scrp.Script(urns.ToArray());
        foreach (string st in sc) {
            // It seems each string is a sensible batch, and putting GO after it makes it work in tools like SSMS.
            // Wrapping each string in an 'exec' statement would work better if using SqlCommand to run the script.
            builder.Append(st.Trim(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }) + "\r\nGO\r\n");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        showExceptionError("Couldn't generate script.", ex);
        return;
    }

    try {
        File.WriteAllText(txtExportToFile.Text, builder.ToString());
        _utils.ShowInfo("DB exported to script at: " + txtExportToFile.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        showExceptionError("Couldn't save script file.", ex);
        return;
    }
}
```

Note that foreign keys fall under the category of DRI constraints, and are scripted because of `scrp.Options.DriAllConstraints = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution here: [Can't get EnumScript() to generate constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19070280/740987)

for some reason, `Scripter` won't emit DRI constraints (foreign keys, etc) when it's given a list of Urns, but it will if it's given one Urn at a time. The trick there is to give the Urns in the order of their ancestry: tables have to be defined before they're referenced by constraints. To do that I've used the `DependencyWalker`.

Here's a synopsis:

```
        var urns = new List<Urn>();
        Scripter schemaScripter = new Scripter(srv) { Options = schemaOptions };
        Scripter insertScripter = new Scripter(srv) { Options = insertOptions };
        var dw = new DependencyWalker(srv);

        foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
            if (t.IsSystemObject == false)
                urns.Add(t.Urn);
        DependencyTree dTree = dw.DiscoverDependencies(urns.ToArray(), true);
        DependencyCollection dColl = dw.WalkDependencies(dTree);

        foreach (var d in dColl)
        {
            foreach (var s in schemaScripter.Script(new Urn[] { d.Urn }))
                strings.Add(s);
            strings.Add("GO");
            if (scriptData)
            {
                int n = 0;
                foreach (var i in insertScripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] {d.Urn}))
                {
                    strings.Add(i);
                    if ((++n) % 100 == 0)
                        strings.Add("GO");
                }
            }
        }
```

Note: adding a "GO" every so often keeps the batch size small so SSMS doesn't run out of memory.